# Only reload a part of a web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page in which a user is asking a question after watching video. I want to update the number of questions asked as soon as any user asks question. I do not want to reload the whole page. I only want to update that specific div which is containing all questions.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`jQuery.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) for this.

For example, wherever you want to refresh some div with id=`questions`, you do this:

```
jQuery('#questions').load('/some_url #questions > *');
```

Comment: Ohh, nice. I didn't know you could pass a selector into load to only update that element.

Comment: @armen.shimoon: Yes, you can. This is neat about jQuery and this specific method, as you are able to add some dynamism to a page at low cost. See my updated answer, it contains corrected selector (you will also see that more complex selectors are possible).

Comment: Tadeck why do you include #questions twice? Surely you have a dedicated url for questions. You answer indicate you fetch the whole page and only use the #questions part. Is that correct? Why?

Comment: `jQuery('#questions').load('/some_url #questions > *');`: load `/some_url`, get all children of #questions `#questions > *` and insert into `#questions`

Comment: i have used this thing already but this is not working for me. You have any other method to do this thing.

Comment: @ShailendraDubey: What exactly is not working? Can you post some details?

Comment: Vitalli why does the returned page contain something that is not supposed to go in questions? That seems lazy.

Comment: i have a div which contains questions related to video and answer posted to the asked question. When user submit any question that question comes under question div. i want to referseh all question (with updated one) after sumition of data but i do not want to reload the page as it stops the running video. can u suggest any soloution. i have used the posted soloution but it is not loading page inside div.

Comment: @EsbenSkovPedersen: This is a technique used pretty commonly, if you have separate URL for separate state, but want to use some nice transitions between pages and yet have some fallback. Try using it, the simplicity of the solution is pretty obvious. However using this solutions without selectors and with proper preparation on the server side (so the server will return only the part that will be entered) will also work. Anyway, this solution is neat and allows for partial updates even without the need to prepare partials on the server side (because the whole page will do also).

Comment: @ShailendraDubey: I cannot help you without more details. I can assure you, that the solution I mentioned works, if you have proper structure (meaning: you have container with specific ID and you want to load only its content from the next version of this page). It is not meant to load page into div, it is meant to load part of the page into the corresponding container.

Answer (score 2):

You add a page to you server which returns only your questions.

e.g. your full page contains

```
<div id="questions"></div>
```

then you design a page /questions.php on your server which returns only what is supposed to be in that div

with jquery.load you fill the questions div

```
<script>$(function(){  $("#questions").load("/questions.php")  })</script>
```